# Parse a txt file and extract specific part depending on list

Tags: python, regex, parsing, fasta

I would need help in order to extract part of a txt.file such as

```
#some comments
#some comments
#some comments
# Predicted genes for sequence number 1 on both strands
# start gene g1
scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    gene    1268    6647    0.19    -   .   g1
scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    transcript  1268    6647    0.19    -   .   g1.t1
scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    stop_codon  1268    1270    .   -   0   transcript_id "g1.t1"; gene_id "g1";
scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    intron  1457    6004    0.62    -   .   transcript_id "g1.t1"; gene_id "g1";
scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    intron  6194    6509    0.42    -   .   transcript_id "g1.t1"; gene_id "g1";
scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    CDS 1268    1456    0.62    -   0   transcript_id "g1.t1"; gene_id "g1";
scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    CDS 6005    6193    0.52    -   0   transcript_id "g1.t1"; gene_id "g1";
scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    CDS 6510    6647    0.3 -   0   transcript_id "g1.t1"; gene_id "g1";
scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    start_codon 6645    6647    .   -   0   transcript_id "g1.t1"; gene_id "g1";
# protein sequence = [MDASLTLHRFRKRGAKRCGISDLKDIRNALRVGEIGPELLQSLATRGLLKKVDCNLVRIWSHMTRQKKKFFEIRVSYH
# HVRTTSKSKLLLVPDTNPDAALQKKMSTRLCTRYGYAITGQRGEIRKIRREMDGQSERQIDGRTHSRAGHLPTDKPSKGAKRCNFSISTFKTV]
# end gene g1
###
# start gene g2
scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    gene    10257   16732   0.03    -   .   g2
scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    transcript  10257   16732   0.03    -   .   g2.t1
scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    stop_codon  10257   10259   .   -   0   transcript_id "g2.t1"; gene_id "g2";
scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    intron  10476   12506   0.18    -   .   transcript_id "g2.t1"; gene_id "g2";
scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    intron  12667   15174   0.18    -   .   transcript_id "g2.t1"; gene_id "g2";
scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    intron  15183   16579   0.2 -   .   transcript_id "g2.t1"; gene_id "g2";
scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    CDS 10257   10475   0.59    -   0   transcript_id "g2.t1"; gene_id "g2";
scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    CDS 12507   12666   0.48    -   1   transcript_id "g2.t1"; gene_id "g2";
scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    CDS 15175   15182   0.21    -   0   transcript_id "g2.t1"; gene_id "g2";
scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    CDS 16580   16732   0.34    -   0   transcript_id "g2.t1"; gene_id "g2";
scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    start_codon 16730   16732   .   -   0   transcript_id "g2.t1"; gene_id "g2";
# protein sequence = [MLAASRYSRRSRKISRVQHWDVNDSRDISACNSLSSEKAPSVTRREWHEMRLLSRSRDRFADCLRTVAARVRGPIKPS
# PCSGRQCETVRWRIENGPLLTDQLAVFAQVRLALASTTSGQHPSGDNVGNDRYATRLYLLTSRGTSLVHRGNELKFDRRRWTNLSTILVYANEILRCE
# EGW]
# end gene g2
###
# start gene g3
scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    gene    21625   24883   0.55    -   .   g3
scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    transcript  21625   24883   0.55    -   .   g3.t1
scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    stop_codon  21625   21627   .   -   0   transcript_id "g3.t1"; gene_id "g3";
scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    intron  21830   22738   0.68    -   .   transcript_id "g3.t1"; gene_id "g3";
scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    intron  22760   22851   0.61    -   .   transcript_id "g3.t1"; gene_id "g3";
scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    intron  22954   24665   0.89    -   .   transcript_id "g3.t1"; gene_id "g3";
scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    CDS 21625   21829   0.91    -   1   transcript_id "g3.t1"; gene_id "g3";
scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    CDS 22739   22759   0.68    -   1   transcript_id "g3.t1"; gene_id "g3";
scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    CDS 22852   22953   0.84    -   1   transcript_id "g3.t1"; gene_id "g3";
scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    CDS 24666   24883   0.84    -   0   transcript_id "g3.t1"; gene_id "g3";
scaffold_0  AUGUSTUS    start_codon 24881   24883   .   -   0   transcript_id "g3.t1"; gene_id "g3";
# protein sequence = [MEYSQIFSPKLQVLSTKERLLTGNRTNISLENTRLGASIELGNPIHKWKPVAEQGSLGIEPSDGSSSLHDLPLYFRTR
# CETSNASTSDRIRKLTIREGKGFDDSQMTCMLIVDKPPKKTLTTLDKEWKEISIRMTTKVISRCDMAANEEDEDSSESIYHAPFEDAPCTVRTSLNFD
# TSALE]
# end gene g3
###
```

So first I have a list such as `list_gene_names=['g1','g3']`

and I would like to loop over that list and extract the protein sequences  (between brackets) and put them into a file called : `sequence_file.fa`

So far I tried :

```
file_to_parse=open('file_to_parse.txt','w')

with open("sequence_file.fa",'a') as sequence_file_output:
  for names in list_gene_names:
    (then we should locate the part between '''# start gene names''' and '''# end gene names''')
    and get the part '''# protein sequence =''' between brackets"
    print('>',names,file=sequence_file_output,sep='')
    print(part_between_brackets,file=sequence_file_output)
```

At the end the file `sequence_file.fa` should look like :

```
>g1
MDASLTLHRFRKRGAKRCGISDLKDIRNALRVGEIGPELLQSLATRGLLKKVDCNLVRIWSHMTRQKKKFFEIRVSYHHVRTTSKSKLLLVPDTNPDAALQKKMSTRLCTRYGYAITGQRGEIRKIRREMDGQSERQIDGRTHSRAGHLPTDKPSKGAKRCNFSISTFKTV
>g2
MEYSQIFSPKLQVLSTKERLLTGNRTNISLENTRLGASIELGNPIHKWKPVAEQGSLGIEPSDGSSSLHDLPLYFRTRCETSNASTSDRIRKLTIREGKGFDDSQMTCMLIVDKPPKKTLTTLDKEWKEISIRMTTKVISRCDMAANEEDEDSSESIYHAPFEDAPCTVRTSLNFDTSALE
```

Thank you for your help and time

Comment: How did you not get an error on that line starting with `(then we should ..`??

Comment: Yes, in fact I said (I tried) but it is more a mixture between a real code, an a code to explain with words what we should do ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex would be one way:

```
import re

regex = r"# start gene(.+?)$[^[]*\[([^\]]*)\]"

with open("sequence_file.fa",'a') as sequence_file_output:
    test_str = sequence_file_output.read()

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
with open("result.txt","w") as f:
  for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
      # restrict to g1,g2:
      if match.group(1).strip() in "g1,g2":  
          for groupNum in range(1, len(match.groups())+1):
              f.write(match.group(groupNum).replace("#",
                  "").replace(" ","").replace("\n",""))
              f.write("\n")

with open("result.txt") as f:
  print(f.read())
```

Output:

```
g1
MDASLTLHRFRKRGAKRCGISDLKDIRNALRVGEIGPELLQSLATRGLLKKVDCNLVRIWSHMTRQKKKFFEIRVSYHHVRTTSKSKLLLVPDTNPDAALQKKMSTRLCTRYGYAITGQRGEIRKIRREMDGQSERQIDGRTHSRAGHLPTDKPSKGAKRCNFSISTFKTV
g2
MLAASRYSRRSRKISRVQHWDVNDSRDISACNSLSSEKAPSVTRREWHEMRLLSRSRDRFADCLRTVAARVRGPIKPSPCSGRQCETVRWRIENGPLLTDQLAVFAQVRLALASTTSGQHPSGDNVGNDRYATRLYLLTSRGTSLVHRGNELKFDRRRWTNLSTILVYANEILRCEEGW
g3
MEYSQIFSPKLQVLSTKERLLTGNRTNISLENTRLGASIELGNPIHKWKPVAEQGSLGIEPSDGSSSLHDLPLYFRTRCETSNASTSDRIRKLTIREGKGFDDSQMTCMLIVDKPPKKTLTTLDKEWKEISIRMTTKVISRCDMAANEEDEDSSESIYHAPFEDAPCTVRTSLNFDTSALE
```

**Regex explanation:**

The pattern looks for `'#start gene'` and captures the name of the thing behind it. It then skips all things up to the first `'['`, captures all things up to the next `']'` for all text.

To write the file you need to postprocess the captured data a bit due to the line splitting and # symbol in it.

Comment: thank a lot ! and what if I just whant to get the output of ```g1``` and ```g3``` from the list ?

Comment: @chipp  only write to the file `if match.group(1).strip() in ["g1,g2"]` or something alike should do it

Comment: Perfect, just the first with ```open("sequence_file.fa",'a') as sequence_file_output:``` should be ````with open(" txt.file",'a') as sequence_file_output:```` and ````with open("result.txt","w") as f:``` should be ```with open("sequence_file.fa","w") as f:```but it works now

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions (module `re`). You have to capture all the text after `# protein sequence = [`

Try this code (this is just begining):

```
import re
regex = r"^# protein sequence = [([A-Z]+)$"
l = re.findall(regex, content_file, re.M)
```

Comment: and how can I use the ```list_gene_names``` information in order to extract a particular ```# protein sequence = [```?

Comment: You can for example start by splitting the content using `###`: `content.split("###")`. You get a list of all genes' information. Then you apply what I wrote to each element of the list